# Enhanced Link Attribution with Universal Analytics

Tags: google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have been attempting to get Enhanced Link Attribution to work with Universal Analytics.  I have given elements unique IDs, enable link attribution from the properties section and added ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js'); to the tracking code with no results.

I am using the following live test page:
http://bit.ly/1LQtjgk

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just double checking here, but you are checking in Behaviour > In-page Analytics? Also, just a note that it is best if your GA code is in the <head> section of your pages.

Comment: yes I have been checking in In Page Analytics, and I usually go for full screen view after prompting because out web pages page do not usually load within an iframe